# REST design - Updating a big resource with a lot of related models

Tags: rest, crud

I'm working on an application which has some very big models. Counting the base table and all of the related tables it's about 30 tables now for describing a Real Estate property.

So the thing is, based on REST, I would have to have like 30 subroutes for a property to update each related model.

/properties
/properties/1
/properties/1/availability
/properties/1/surfaces
/properties/1/extras
/properties/1/images

...

A property really has a lot of things related to it, trust me.

Now this design above looks really cool but when it comes to working with it, it migth be a bit cumbersome.

I have 2 clients, one is an internal company dashboard and the other one is a dashboard for our users.

They have a nice view of everything that is attached to a property and can modify it by changing data in form fields and clicking "submit".

Rigth now I'm mixing a bit of what they call:

> Fine grained CRUD resources versus Coarse Grained resources

Which means that you can POST /properties/1 with a huge JSON object and change some related models.

If I would apply perfect REST API design I would end up making 30 requests everytime a user hits the save button.

Is it correct to updated related models (let's say you can change some basic data but also the availability the extras and the images) by making a PUT request to the main resource (/properties/1) instead of "properties/1/images"?.

Not sure if this is directly stackoverflow related. I apologize in advance if it's not.

Comment: According to [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) *A PUT request applied to the target resource **can**  have side effects on other resources*. The server is also allowed to decide which data belongs to the resource and may also transform data to match the current representation. You should however not perform partial updates with PUT, use `PATCH` or `POST` therefore

Comment: So I would have to send a PUT request with all 30 related models and it's changes to the main resource enpoint, or a POST / PUT with only partial data?

Comment: If you read the section that describes PUT it is clear under which circumstances sideeffects are ok. Generally speaking if you have to modify plenty of resources at the same time, `PATCH` (i.e. [JsonPatch](http://jsonpatch.com/)) is probably the safer alternative as it has to be applied atomically (either fully or not at all). You are of course free to also use `POST` as the semantics here are defined by you

Answer (score 0):

> So the thing is, based on REST, I would have to have like 30 subroutes for a property to update each related model.

Most important question to ask when designing a REST API

> How would I do this as a web site?

If your answer is: "I would have 30 different pages that clients could load and modify", then knock yourself out.

You *might* find that applying the principles of a [task based ui](https://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/task-based-ui/) will be some help.

> Is it correct to updated related models (let's say you can change some basic data but also the availability the extras and the images) by making a PUT request to the main resource (/properties/1) instead of "properties/1/images"?.

As Roman Vottner already noted - yes, RFC 7231 makes it explicit that the modification of one resource can have side effects elsewhere.  Fundamentally, HTTP describes *semantics*, not *implementation*.  What you do in the black box is up to you -- the only constraints are on the messages exchanged and their interpretations.

HTTP cares a lot less about how you update your model(s) than it does about which cached representations your modifications invalidate.